# As3 NetStream ns.seek() does not work

Tags: actionscript-3, mp3, netstream

```
  public function seek( percent:Number ):void
            {
                var p:Number = Math.floor( ( nsClient.length * percent / 100 ) );
                trace( "netstream length is: " + nsClient.length + " and to go num is: " + p );
                try
                {
                    ns.seek( p );
                }
                catch (e:Error)
                {
                    trace( e );
                }
            }
```

i am using this code to seek a netstream and it is showing perfect calculations as

netstream length is: 54.12 and to go num is: 25

but player does not work on using seek, what is going wrong here?